# How to display the alert box in server side in mvc controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, alert

I need to display the alert box in server side in mvc controller with number of id . Only on server side . I try the below Code but not working . How we do that? Thank you fro Your Advance help

Code:

```
if (condition)
               {

    StringBuilder tt = new StringBuilder();

    tt.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        tt.Append("alert('" + id + "')");
    }
    tt.Append("</script>");
}
```

Comment: Post the whole code, where and how you are rendering the tt value.

Comment: No of course he does not want to show dialog on the server. He want to generate dialog on the server. BUT there is some code missing. Can you post the whole action in which you are trying to achieve this?

Comment: I Try this level only just i need to display the append id value to end user

Answer (score 0):

The partial code is missing from your question still you can do it like this.

considering the above code it is expected that you store the "tt" in your model or view data like this at your controller side..

```
if (condition)
 {
    StringBuilder tt = new StringBuilder();
    tt.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        tt.Append("alert('" + id + "')");
    }
    tt.Append("</script>");
   Response.Write(tt.ToString());

}
```

In that case it would work.

Comment: No i didn't goes to the client side

Comment: Response.Write(tt.ToString()); not working its does not show the alert box. WE can add anything for  Response.Write?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work if you have more than 1 id in ids collection because that will generate code like this

alert(1)alert(2)...etc

It will also not work if your ids collection is empty (because it will not generate any alerts on the client).

You need to add `;` after `alert('" + id + "')` like this:

```
StringBuilder tt = new StringBuilder();
tt.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
foreach (var id in ids)
{
    tt.Append("alert('" + id + "');");
}
tt.Append("</script>");
Response.Write(tt.ToString());
```

Comment: Its loaded currently. But not display the popup window

Comment: View the HTML source and post it here. Could be a syntax error. Are you getting any JS errors?

Comment: @User279_1 yes, it would be good if you post your source here so we could see if you have a syntax error.